# Multiple errors in SQL expression

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, annotations

I want to use this SQL query in Eclipse but I get error

```
@Query("select @ref:=id as id, unique_id, reference_id "+
           "from mytable join (select @ref:=id from mytable WHERE unique_id = :pUid) tmp "+
           "where reference_id=@ref",
            nativeQuery = true) 
   List<MyTable> myCustomHirachicalQuery(@Param("pUid") Integer uid)
```

But I get these errors in Eclipse:

`Syntax error on token ",",` and `[ expected Syntax error, insert "]" to complete Expression`

[image]

Do you know how I can solve these issues?

Comment: Is this Spring or something?

Comment: Yes, native Spring query.

Comment: Next time tag it appropriately please

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not specific for Spring, `@Query` or SQL, but is due to
the general syntax rules for Java annotations.

The [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html) annotation has among others these attributes:

- `String value`
- `boolean nativeQuery`

Java's annotation syntax handles the `value` attribute in a special way.

If you want to set the `value` attribute only,
then you can do it with or without `value=`:
By `@Query(value = "select ...")` or simply by `@Query("select ...")`.

But if you want to set more attributes besides the `value` attribute,
then it is not to allowed to omit `value=`. You need to write
`@Query(value = "select ...", nativeQuery = true)` instead of
`@Query("select ...", nativeQuery = true)`.